# Can't find wandering magician after purchase

Tags: snoopys-street-fair

I just bought the wandering magician (which is on sale). However, after I updated the app, I can't seem to find where it has gone.

Answer (score 1):

He does wander around your fair - so he might not be in the same place as he was last time you looked. Sometimes he gets stuck behind other images but if you wait, you should see him.